# Establishing $\frac{ \sin mx}{\sin x}=(-4)^{(m-1)/2}\prod_{1\leq j\leq(m-1)/2}\left(\sin^2x-\sin^2\frac{2\pi j}{m}\right) $ for odd $m$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $m$ be an odd positive integer. Prove that
>
> $$ \dfrac{ \sin (mx) }{\sin x } = (-4)^{\frac{m-1}{2}} \prod_{1 \leq j
>  \leq \frac{(m-1)}{2} }  \left( \sin^2 x - \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{ 2 \pi
>  j }{m } \right) \right) $$

### Atempt to the proof

My idea is to use induction on $m$. The base case is $m=3$ and we obtain

$$ \dfrac{ \sin (3x) }{\sin x } = (-4) ( \sin^2 x - \sin^2 (2 \pi /3 ) ) $$

and this holds if one uses the well known $\sin (3x) = 3 \sin x - 4 \sin^3 x $ identity.

Now, if we assume the result is true for $m = 2k-1$, then we prove it holds for $m=2k+1$. We have

$$ \dfrac{ \sin (2k + 1) x }{\sin x } = \dfrac{ \sin [(2k-1 + 2 )x] }{\sin x } = \dfrac{ \sin[(2k-1)x ] \cos (2x) }{\sin x } + \dfrac{ \cos [(2k-1) x ] \sin 2x }{\sin x }  $$

And this is equivalent to

$$ cos(2x) \cdot (-4)^{k-1} \prod_{1 \leq j
 \leq k-1  }\left( \sin^2 x - \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{ 2 \pi
 j }{m } \right) \right) + 2 \cos [(2k-1) x ] \cos x $$

Here I dont see any way to simplify it further. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Formally, when $\sin x=0$ then the lfet-hand side of the required equality is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer can be seen as supplement of @Conrads answer providing some more details.

> We start with the right-hand side of OPs identity. Letting $m=2k+1$ we obtain:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(-4)^k}&\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^k\left(\sin^2(x)-\sin^2\left(\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)}\\
> &=(-4)^k\prod_{j=1}^k\left[\sin\left(x+\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\sin\left(x-\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right]\tag{1}\\
> &=4^k\prod_{j=1}^k\left[\sin\left(x+\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\sin\left(\left(x-\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)-\pi\right)\right]\tag{2}\\
> &=4^k\left(\prod_{j=1}^k\sin\left(x+\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^k\sin\left(x+\frac{(2k+1-2j)\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=4^k\left(\prod_{j=1}^k\sin\left(x+\frac{2j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^k\sin\left(x+\frac{(2j-1)\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=4^k\left(\prod_{{j=1}\atop{j\ even}}^{2k}\sin\left(x+\frac{j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)\left(\prod_{{j=1}\atop{j\ odd}}^{2k}\sin\left(x+\frac{j\pi}{2k+1}\right)\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4^k\prod_{j=1}^{2k}\sin\left(x+\frac{j\pi }{2k+1}\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we recall the trigonometric addition formulas
  \begin{align*}
  \sin(x+y)&=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)\\
  \sin(x-y)&=\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)
  \end{align*}
  and get
  \begin{align*}
  \sin&(x+y)\sin(x-y)\\
  &=\left(\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)\right)\left(\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)\right)\\
  &=\sin^2(x)\cos^2(y)-\cos^2(x)\sin^2(y)\\
  &=\sin^2(x)\left(1-\sin^2(y)\right)-\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right)\sin^2(y)\\
  &=\sin^2(x)-\sin^2(y)
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we use the identity $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi -x)$ and factor out $(-1)^k$ by using $\sin(x)=-\sin(-x)$.
- In (3) we use $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)$ and we split the product as preparation for the next steps.
- In (4) we change the order of the multiplication in the right-hand product $j\to k-j+1$.
- In (5) we do not change anything. We just write the index region somewhat more conveniently to better see the next step, where the products can be merged.

> In order to simplify (6) we recall Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{4^k}&\color{blue}{\prod_{j=0}^{2k}\sin\left(x+\frac{j\pi }{2k+1}\right)}\\
> &=4^k\prod_{j=0}^{2k}\left[\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\left(x+\frac{j\pi }{2k+1}\right)}-e^{-i\left(x+\frac{j\pi }{2k+1}\right)}\right)\right]\tag{7}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2i}\prod_{j=0}^{2k}\left[e^{-i\left(x+\frac{j\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\left(1-e^{2i\left(x+\frac{j\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\right)\right]\tag{8}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2i}e^{-i(2k+1)x}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{2k}j}
> \prod_{j=0}^{2k}\left(1-e^{2i\left(x+\frac{j\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\right)\tag{9}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2i}e^{-i(2k+1)x}e^{-ik\pi}
> \prod_{j=0}^{2k}\left(1-\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2k+1}}\right)^j e^{2ix}\right)\tag{10}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)}{2i}e^{-i(2k+1)x}
> \left(1-\left(e^{2ix}\right)^{2k+1} \right)\tag{11}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{(2k+1)ix}-e^{-(2k+1)ix}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sin((2k+1)x)}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (7) we use the identity $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)$.
- In (8) we factor out $\left(\frac{1}{2i}\right)^{2k+1}$ from the product and within the product $e^{-i\left(x+\frac{j\pi}{2k+1}\right)}$.
- In (9) we factor out some more terms which do not depend on the index $j$.
- In (10) we use the summation formula $\sum_{j=1}^{2k}j = \frac{1}{2}(2k)(2k+1)$ , the identity $e^{ik\pi}=(-1)^k$ and we write the factor in the product in the form
  \begin{align*}
  1-\omega ^j z
  \end{align*}
  with $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2k+1}}$ the $(2k+1)$-st *[root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition)*.
- In (11) we use the representation with $\omega$ the root of unity and $z=e^{2ix}$.
  \begin{align*}
  \prod_{j=0}^{2k}\left(1-z\omega^j\right)=\left(1+z+\cdots+z^{2k}\right)(1-z)=1-z^{2k+1}
  \end{align*}

Comment: @James: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. 

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\sin (x-\frac{2\pi j }{m})=-\sin(x+\frac{(m-2j)\pi}{m})$ and $m-2j$ goes through the odd numbers $1,...m-2$ when $ 1\le j \le \frac{m-1}{2}$

By the paralelogram rule for sine $\sin^2 x- \sin^2 y=\sin(x-y)\sin(x+y)$ so we get that the RHS product

$P=\sin x  \prod_{1 \leq j
 \leq \frac{(m-1)}{2} }  \left( \sin^2 x - \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{ 2 \pi
 j }{m } \right) \right)=(-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}\prod_{0 \leq j
 \leq m-1}\sin (x+\frac{j\pi}{m})=$

$=(-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}2^{-(m-1)}\sin mx$ by the classic product formula, so we are done!

(the product formula is obtained by taking the imaginary part of both sides in $e^{2imx}-1=\Pi_{k=0,..m-1} {(e^{2ix}-e^{-\frac{2\pi ik}{m}})}$)

Comment: What is the classical product formula?

Comment: Shouldnt we have to specify in the problem as well that $x $ better not be $n \pi$ ?

Comment: Im not seeing how you got second equality in the sixth line. Where did the sinx multiplying the product go ??

Comment: $\sin x$ is the term for $j=0$ in the 6th line and the equality holds for $n\pi$ (in the OP ratio formulation understanding that as the usual limit $m$, in the product formula both sides being zero - one goes from one to another here by analytic continuation, though one can make an argument from continuity for example - the classic product formula is the last line of the argument $\prod_{0 \leq j
 \leq m-1}\sin (x+\frac{j\pi}{m})=2^{-(m-1)}\sin mx$, holds for any $m \ge 1$ odd or even - odd here matters only  in the first line

Comment: Why would the bounds change from $0 \leq j \leq (m-1)/2$ to $0 \leq j \leq m $ ?

Comment: First line shows that (each term in the original product is a product of two terms by the rule of the difference of squares of sines - parallelogram rule) and because $m$ odd the terms with minus in the argument become precisely the required missing terms in the final product)

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment: Look up [Chebyshev polynomial of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). They are literally what you are dealing with:
$$U_n(\cos x) = \dfrac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin x}.$$

Your attempt at induction basically reduces it to an equivalent problem that uses the first kind of Chebyshev polynomials, so I would not be fixated on inductive approach.